# sql query how to - compare values in the column of two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Sire,

I'm having two tables tab1 and tab2 with the details below

tab1-(Name is in the order Firstname, MiddleName, LastName)

```
------------------------------------
Mobile No.     | Name               
------------------------------------
987654323      | Rahul Ajay Patil        
------------------------------------
98765456       | Amit Mahesh Meshram       
------------------------------------
987654343      | Jyoti Shankar Rao        
------------------------------------
987654543      | Vishesh Ranjit Sahu     
------------------------------------
```

tab2-(Name is in the order Lastname, FirstName, Middlename)

```
-----------------------------------
 Name               
------------------------------------
 Patil Rahul Ajay       
------------------------------------
 Gupta Anil Ramesh       
------------------------------------
 Kulkarni Jyoti Shankar        
------------------------------------
 Sahu  Vishesh Ranjit    
------------------------------------
```

I want to get the result like this

```
------------------------------------
Mobile No.     | Name               
------------------------------------
987654323      | Rahul Ajay Patil        
------------------------------------
987654543      | Vishesh Ranjit Sahu     
------------------------------------
```

Please Help.

Comment: Well, everything you need is in your `tab1`, yes?  I don't see any need for `tab2`.  This is pretty basic, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Read question again, it seems he wants rows from tab1, if name exists in tab2, however names are not identical

Comment: Respected Sirs, 
    I'm having name of the person in my application database with the format as (Lastname Firstname Middlename) and a third party database with name(format as Firstname Middlename Lastname) and number of some person matching my application database. I need to get the name and numbers of the persons whose names are matching in the two database. 
Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not optimal solution, but it works and I hope it's what you tried to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 t1 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM tab2 t2 
  WHERE t2.Name = 
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Name, ' ', -1),
    ' ', 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Name, ' ', 2)
  )
);
```

SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15a71/29